# Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH connection failure

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, centos, vscode-remote

So I've been able to connect over SSH to the server using a shell, and now I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH. The SSH connection seems successful but then I get prompted with *"Could not establish connection to ... . The VS Code Server failed to start."*

Any ideas what the problem might be?

- Local OS: Windows 10 with native SSH client
- Remote OS: CentOS 7 (without sudo rights)
- Logs:

```
[14:39:44.369] > 
Server did not start successfully. Full server log >>>
/users/XXX/.vscode-server/bin/f359dd69833dd8800b54d458f6d37ab7c78df520/server.sh: line 12: 26789 
Aborted                 "$ROOT/node" ${INSPECT:-} "$ROOT/out/vs/server/main.js" "$@"
[14:26:33.056]
<<< End of server log
b65f23a8e10a##32##
[14:26:33.607] "install" terminal command done
[14:26:33.608] Install terminal quit with output: b65f23a8e10a##32##
[14:26:33.608] Received install output: b65f23a8e10a##32##
[14:26:33.611] Resolver error: The VS Code Server failed to start
[14:26:33.618] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"failure","reason":"ExitCode","askedPw":"0","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0","remoteInConfigFile":"1"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"exitCode":32,"retries":1}}
[14:26:33.622] ------
```

- Telemetry properly formatted:

```
{
  "eventName":"resolver",
  "properties": { 
    "outcome":"failure",
    "reason":"ExitCode",
    "askedPw":"0",
    "askedPassphrase":"0",
    "asked2fa":"0",
    "askedHostKey":"0",
    "gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0",
    "remoteInConfigFile":"1"
  },
  "measures":{
    "resolveAttempts":1,
    "exitCode":32,
    "retries":1
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: try running a command over normal ssh -- e.g. ssh hostname ls -al to see if you get an issue.

Comment: SSH connection over shell doesn't give me any issues, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the SSH-server didn't support VS Code for some reason. I solved my problem by creating a `ProxyCommand` in `~/.ssh/config` to another internal machine, which did support VS Code.

Comment: I seem to be facing the same, or at least a very similar, issue. Could you elaborate on what versions would seem to be incompatible?

Comment: The one that didn't work (the ssh server) is CentOS 8, the one that did (which I proxied into) is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, so I try running server.sh from your console that is inside of:

```
~/.vscode-server/bin/622**************************/server.sh
```

Mine showed missing libatomic1 `library`.

Once installed, everything works as it should.

Comment: For me, I didn't have node installed.

Comment: Where is `.vscode-server`? I can't find it.

Comment: It should be inside of your home folder and by default will be hidden from your file explorer. You could check if it exists by running: cd ~/.vscode-server/

Answer (score 1):

*VS Code*: **File** > **Preferences** > **Setting**s >
*and search for* `@ext:ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh,ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit config file` then type the absolute file path of your ssh config file.

[image]